# Do Typescript Interfaces allow you to discard attributes not defined on the interface?

Tags: interface, typescript

I have a function that performs a search. The search can be done a few different ways (by looking for an ID or by querying a few attributes). However, I want to limit what attributes can be passed in. I thought I could do something like:

```
interface Search {
  _id?: string
  people?: number
  partyName?: string
  otherField? string
}

function search(query: Search) {
    myDbConnection.find(query).then(... // etc
}
```

The problem is that any object will conform to this, and `query` can contain extra attributes. For example, this could be passed:

```
search({otherField: "foo", aProtectedField: "bar"})
```

and `aProtectedField` would be passed along to `find`.

I am wondering if there is a typescript way of enforcing the attributes passed. Sort of strong-parameters from the Rails world. I know I can do things like `pick` form lodash or maybe even make a `SearchObject` class and use the constructor as a means of discarding the extra attributes, but I feel like there is a way to do this within Typescript that I just don't know about.

Answer (score 0):

You could make all the properties required then do an assertion to pass in a subset of the properties.

For example:

```
interface Search {
  _id: string;
  people: number;
  partyName: string;
  otherField: string;
}

function search(query: Search) {
    // code here
}

search({ people: 2 } as Search); // ok
search({ otherField: "foo", aProtectedField: "bar" }); // error, good
search({ otherField: "foo", aProtectedField: "bar" } as Search); // error, good
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Typescript are you on? Since Typescript 1.6 there has been [improved checking for object literals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks).

On TS 1.8 when I try to run your code I get:

> error TS2345: Argument of type '{ otherField: string; aProtectedField: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Search'.
>     Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'aProtectedField' does not exist in type 'Search'.

This and noImplicitAny should catch the errors you're worried about.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to limit what attributes can be passed in. [...] query can contain extra attributes.

The way I see it, this is controversial. If you limit what attributes a given object might contain, then it is, by definition, limited to that set of attributes, and cannot contain others not allowed by its specs.

Since there is practically nothing you can do about the `any` type, my recommendation is to resolve this the type-safe way, by defining an option for additional attributes:

```
interface Search {
    _id?: string;
    people?: number;
    partyName?: string;
    additionalFields?: { [key: string]: any };
}
```

```auto
search({ people: 2 }); // ok
search({ _id: "jd", people: 2 }); // ok
search({ _id: "jd", additionalFields: { otherField: "foo" } }); // ok
```